# Class POD members default-initialization vs. zero-initialization vs. no-initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

There are many questions on this topic but many of them use inaccurate terms and the answers are mostly partial. I will try to ask it in yet a another way and hopefully come up with a polished answer to this frequent question.

1. What is the difference, if any, between default-initialization and zero-initialization in the case of PODs?
2. If a member POD variable is not initialized in the constructor initialization list, in which case will it be:

   - zero-initialized.
   - default-initialized (if different from above).
   - left uninitialized.
3. Does the answer to question 2 above depend on whether the instance of the class is created on the stack or on the heap using the `new` operator
4. Is the answer to any of the above questions different for C++98,C++11 or C++14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In default initialization, basic "C"-style types (int, double, char, bool, etc.) have indeterminate values.  That is, there is no undefined behavior, but the values could be anything.
2. If a POD member is not initialized in the constructor nor via C++11 in-class initialization, it is default-initialized.
3. The answer is the same regardless of stack or heap.
4. In C++98 (and not afterward), `new int()` was specified as performing zero initialization.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: So default initialization is no-initialization in the case of PODs?

Comment: @mustafa: Yeah, as per the page I linked "Otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values."