# Why am I getting error while initializing a struct with curly braces?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++17, curly-braces

I am using the below code and getting error. I don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:15:44: error: could not convert ‘{"foo", true}’ from 
                       ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘option’
                       option x[] = {{"foo", true},{"bar", false}};
                                            ^
prog.cpp:15:44: error: could not convert ‘{"bar", false}’ from 
                       ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ o ‘option’
```

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
struct option
{
    option();
    ~option();
 
    std::string s;
    bool b;
};
 
option::option() = default;
option::~option() = default;

int main()
{
    option x[] = {{"foo", true},{"bar", false}};
}
```

Comment: Just remove the default constructor and destructor or add a constructor that takes two arguments.

Comment: What version of C++ are you compiling against?  The rules for aggregates have changed in every version so it matters.

Comment: IMO, I think that the braces reduces encapsulation for the `option` class if the two argument constructor isn't provided.  Why must the user know that there are two member variables that can be set like that?  I could understand something like `vector<int>`, where you know that you use `int`'s to populate the object, but `option`?  Provide the proper constructors that makes it evident that an `option` consists of two values, and the constructor of `object` figures out how to set those values.

Answer (score 6):

When you **provide**<sup>**†**</sup> the default constructor and destructor, you are making the struct be a *[non-aggregate type, hence aggregate initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)* is not possible.

However, you can check if a type is an aggregate using the standard [`std::is_aggregate_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_aggregate) trait. (Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)).

[See here for your case](https://godbolt.org/z/BkdvyF). It is not an aggregate, as you **provided**<sup>**†**</sup> those constructors.

You have the following three ways to make this work:

- Remove the constructors and [you are good to go](https://godbolt.org/z/aRFgxZ).

  ```
  struct option
  {
     std::string s;
     bool b;
  };
  ```
- [Default the constructors inside the struct](https://godbolt.org/z/sD7Lbn) (i.e. **declaring**<sup>**†**</sup>).

  ```
  struct option 
  {    
     std::string s;
     bool b;

     option() = default;
     ~option() = default;
  };
  ```
- Otherwise, you need to [provide a suitable constructor in your `struct`](https://godbolt.org/z/J5atNx).

  ```
  struct option 
  {
     std::string mStr;
     bool mBool;

     option(std::string str, bool b)
        : mStr{ std::move(str) }
        , mBool{ b }
     {}

     // other constructors...
  };
  ```

---

<sup>**†**</sup> The following post explains when the constructor will be `default`ed, when it is considered as **user-declared** and **user-provided** clearly: (*Credits [@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver)*)

[C++ zero initialization - Why is `b` in this program uninitialized, but `a` is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350114/c-zero-initialization-why-is-b-in-this-program-uninitialized-but-a-is-i/54350350#54350350)

Comment: is there any other way without removing the default constructor.

Comment: @AshutoshKumarRay You can add a constructor that takes two arguments.

Comment: It's a little more subtle then your answer makes it seem.  For instance, this compiles fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/856bbadf418fe86a

Comment: @JeJo but this one is, and it has the members explicitly defaulted: https://godbolt.org/z/o6q-Z7

Comment: When declaring a constructor inside the class as default, it is considered a user-declared constructor.  When defaulting it outside the class, it is a user-provided constructor.  Depending on the version of C++, that will make a difference if it is an aggregate or not.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350114/c-zero-initialization-why-is-b-in-this-program-uninitialized-but-a-is-i/54350350#54350350